# using the toString method to display information in an arraylist without brackets and commas

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I am using a toString method to display data in an arraylist. How do I write the code so that it displays the information without the [  , , ] around my information

see the code below:

```
case 6:
            System.out.println("Enter an account number to view the transactions of the account");
            number=keyboard.nextLong();
            found=false;
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<aBank.getAccounts().size();i++){

                if(aBank.getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber().compareTo(number)==0){
                    found=true;
                    System.out.println("Account " + number + ":\tStart Balance: " +money.format(aBank.getAccounts().get(i).getStartBalance()));
                    System.out.println(aBank.getAccounts().get(i).getTransaction().toString());
                    System.out.println("Ending Balance :" +money.format(aBank.getAccounts().get(i).getBalance()));
                }
                }
            }

        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to process request.\n" +e.getMessage());
        }
            break;
```

this is the output:

```
Account 1:  Start Balance: $1000.00
[Deposit    1   6/6/2011    $500.00
, Deposit   2   6/6/2011    $489.00
, Deposit   3   6/6/2011    $262.00
, Withdrawal    4   6/6/2011    $897.00
, Withdrawal    5   6/6/2011    $56.32
, Withdrawal    6   6/6/2011    $78.24
]
Ending Balance :$1219.44
```

notice the brackets and commas that need to be removed

Answer (score 3):

Don't use toString() at all.  It is not meant to be used to create formatted UI strings.  It is a developer tool, not a user presentation tool.

I will add a caveat for the cases where the object represents something with a simple accepted format that can serve both purposes.  Java primitive wrappers (like Integer and Float) are an example of this.  Other simple classes such as a 2D point can work in this regard as well, but this quickly falls apart as an object becomes more complex.

To do what you are attempting, just create a method to do your display and do the formatting in that method instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [guava joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable%29) as in

```
Joiner.on("").join(
    aBank.getAccounts().get(i).getTransaction())
```

Comment: You probably want to space at least between values

Comment: @Peter, unless I'm reading the example wrong, I don't think the OPer wants space since the values seem to be terminated with newlines.  See the lines starting with `, Deposit` in the example.

Comment: @Mike, Fair point.  I would suggest a toString which should be one line having new lines is a bad idea. The formatting should be left to the caller. If this is the case, some of the formatting is done by the caller and some by the callee which is likely to cause confusion.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, In general I agree.  The `toString` method is often used for debugging and to be good for debugging, the output should fit on one line.  But some objects are representations of portions of text -- `StringBuilder` comes to mind as do representations of user inputs and objects whose responsibility is to present data.  Those (semi?)-structured representations should not have the same restrictions as the debug use-case.

Comment: @Mike, Often you want to use more than one formatting. Perhaps `toString` isn't the best place for formatted output.

Comment: @Peter, I agree.  But when what you are representing is involved in the lifecycle of a string by virtue of deriving from a string or being used to produce a string, then there arguably isn't a better debug representation.  What should `StringBuilder.toString` produce?  What about http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use the toString() Method?
Otherwise you could build up the string for each array by yourself.

```
tmpArray = aBank.getAccounts().get(i).getTransaction();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String value : tmpArray) {
  builder.append(value);
}    
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: You probably want to space at least between values.

Comment: Sure, above snippet shows the simplest way of avoiding toString() for printing the strings inside the array.
One could try to add new line after each member is printed, just like 
    builder.append(value+"\n");

Answer (score 1):

Modify the "toString" method of the Object returned by "getTransaction()" !?

Comment: That object appears to be an `ArrayList`, so I don't think this is an option.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
List<String> list = ArrayList<String>();
String asString = list.toString().replaceAll("^\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]$", "").replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it more readable.

```
   try {
    for(BankAccount ba : aBank.getAccounts()) {
      if(ba.getAccountNumber().equals(number)) {
        found=true;
        System.out.println("Account " + number + ":\tStart Balance: " 
         +money.format(ba.getStartBalance()));                  
        for (Object tr : ba.getTransaction()) {
          System.out.println(tr);
        }
        System.out.println("Ending Balance :" +money.format(ba.getBalance()));
       }
      }
}
```