# Removing [] from ArrayList Output and Storing in HashMap<String,Object>

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

I have a HashMap. The key will be a string and value can be anything ranging from a variable to a ArrayList.

The problem is I have an ArrayList. The values stored in the ArrayList are Region1,Region2,Region3,Region4.

So when I put this ArrayList in HashMap and print the HashMap I get the output as 
[Region1,Region2,Region3,Region4].

Problem is I need to insert this whole comma separated String in Db and my procedure cannot recognize [] in this output.

How can I solve it..I cannot change anything at DB end.
Here's the code snippet:-

```
ArrayList<String> Region=new ArrayList<String>();
        Region.add("Region1");
        Region.add("Region2");
        Region.add("Region3");
        System.out.println(Region);

Output is [Region1, Region2, Region3]
```

I put this ArrayList in HashMap

```
HashMap<String,Object> regionHashMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        regionHashMap.put("regionssss", Region);
        System.out.println(regionHashMap);

Output is {regionssss=[Region1, Region2, Region3]}.
```

How can i Remove [] from the ArrayList...

I already succedded by using StringBuffer and Iterator but I cannot use it everytime Since I have huge number of ArrayList which will go inside the HashMap..

Comment: 'I already succedded by using StringBuffer and Iterator but I cannot use it everytime Since I have huge number of ArrayList which will go inside the HashMap', do you mean you have succeeded in creating the script by iterating on the list but feel there could be a performance overhead? Well, even the default implementation of toString in ArrayList does the [same thing](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/AbstractCollection-source.html), so go ahead and use your implementation. I wonder why you want to store comma separated values in database though?

Comment: @aishwarya I have my own reasons of inserting CSV in DB...I cannot help it as I am bounded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String representation of a List automatically encloses with "[ ]" characters.
You could either create your own 'toString' method:

```
private String listToString(List<?> l) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(l.get(i));
        if (i != l.size() -1) sb.append(", ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or, you could use the substring function to remove the braces:

```
String s = list.toString();
s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
```

Comment: Second Method seems to be more useful...Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use toString() at all. It is not meant to be used to create formatted UI strings. It is a developer tool, not a user presentation tool.

To do what you want is to just create a method to do your display and do the formatting in that method instead.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252973/using-the-tostring-method-to-display-information-in-an-arraylist-without-bracket) post to get more on this.

Comment: Can you please give me a code snippet...I wouold be tahnkful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing HashMap and override the toString() method